# How to use x-editable with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, x-editable

I would like to understand using x-editable in my CodeIgniter first project. I tried to read x-editable docs but I'm beginner in JavaScript too so I can't understand

I make simple controller to collect data from JavaScript but I didn't complete it or data not updated in database.

```
$('#username').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
});
```

How to get submitted data in controller or model to process database update query

I want to passing data submitted from x-editable to model to update it in database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow this simple steps 
Assume that $userId = 5 ; $username = "admin";
Consider you html look like this

```
<a type="text" name="username" onclick="setEditable(this);" data-pk="<?php echo $userId ;?>" data-placeholder="Enter Username" data-name="username" data-type="text" data-url="<?php echo site_url();?>user/updateUserName" data-value="<?php echo $username ;?>" data-prev="admin"  data-title="Enter Username"><?php $username; ?></a>
```

In Javascript code write following

$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

```
function setEditable(obj) {
    $(obj).editable({
        emptytext: $(obj).attr('data-value'),
        toggle: 'dblclick',
        mode: 'inline',
        anim: 200,
        onblur: 'cancel',
        validate: function(value) {
            /*Add Ur validation logic and message here*/
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Username is required!';
            }

        },
        params: function(params) {
            /*originally params contain pk, name and value you can pass extra parameters from here if required */
            //eg . params.active="false";
            return params;
        },
        success: function(response, newValue) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(response);
            $(obj).parent().parent().find('.edit-box').show();
            $(obj).attr('data-value', result.username);
            $(obj).attr('data-prev', result.username);

        },
        error: function(response, newValue) {
            $(obj).parent().parent().find('.edit-box').hide();
            if (!response.success) {
                return 'Service unavailable. Please try later.';
            } else {
                return response.msg;
            }

        },
        display: function(value) {
            /*If you want to truncate*/
            var strName = strname !== '' ? strname : $(obj).attr('data-value');
            var shortText = '';
            if (strName.length > 16)
            {
                shortText = jQuery.trim(strName).substring(0, 14).split("").slice(0, -1).join("") + "...";
            }
            else {
                shortText = strName;
            }
            $(this).text(shortText);
        }
    });
    $(obj).editable('option', 'value', $(obj).attr('data-value'));    
}
```

In Controller site

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function updateUserName()
    {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

            $valueStr = $this->input->get_post('value') ? $this->input->get_post('value') : '';
            $new_nameStr = trim($valueStr);
            $result_arr['username'] = $new_nameStr;
            $userId = $this->input->get_post('pk') ? $this->input->get_post('pk') : '';
            $data['username'] = $new_nameStr;
            $result_arr['username'] = $new_nameStr;
            $this->user_model->userUpdateFunction($data, $userId);
        }
        echo json_encode($result_arr);
        exit;
    }
}
```

You can change editable mode , i have set inline only

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this question is about `AJAX` and `JavaScript/jQuery`, not `Codeigniter`.

Basically, the code that you wrote is about posting data with AJAX. First, you need to create a controller and model, then you can post data with AJAX. I'm adding a sample code:

Controller file:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sample extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this ->load ->model('modelfolder/sample_model');   
   }

   public function index() {
      $this->sample_model->sampleFunction();
   }
}
```

Model File:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sample_model extends CI_Model {

   function sampleFunction() {
      $data = array('fieldName' => $this->input->post('userName', TRUE));
      $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('userId', TRUE));
      $this->db->update('tableName', $data);
      return true;
   }
}
```

routes.php File:

```
$route['demoPost'] = 'controller_folder/sample';
```

View File's HTML part:

```
<form id="sampleForm">
 <input type="text" name="userId" />
 <input type="text" name="userName" />
</form>
```

View File's AJAX part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sampleForm").submit(    
        function(){ 
         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo site_url('demoPost'); ?>",
          data: $("#sampleForm").serialize(),
         });
      });
   });
```

Comment: Model user guide here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html and controller user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html